# jsf returns an object and not my object after update ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a problem with my form, I explain:
I want when the user choose a client that the contact list update with the new list of contacts correspondent to the client chosen.
My autocomplete works fine.
My form:

```
<p:outputLabel for="clientDelivery"
                    value="#{msg['material-newDelivery.clientDelivery']}" />
                <p:autoComplete id="clientDelivery" dropdown="true"
                    value="#{deliveryNew.client}"
                    completeMethod="#{deliveryNew.complete}"
                    converter="clientConverter" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.toString()}"
                    itemValue="#{c}" forceSelection="true" required="true">
                    <p:ajax update="contactDelivery" execute="@this" listener="#{deliveryNew.selectOneMenuListener}"/>
                </p:autoComplete>

                <p:outputLabel for="contactDelivery"
                    value="#{msg['material-newDelivery.contactDelivery']}" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="contactDelivery"
                    value="#{deliveryNew.contact}" required="true"
                    converter="contactConverter" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.lastName}" itemValue="#{c}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{deliveryNew.contacts}" var="c"
                        itemLabel="#{c.toString()}" itemValue="#{c}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

my managed bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    contacts = contactDao.findAll();
    contacts.sort(new ContactComparator());
}

public void selectOneMenuListener() {
    this.contacts.clear();
    this.contacts = contactDao.getByClient(client.getId());   
}

public List<Client> complete(String query){
    return clientDao.getByClientNameAll(query);    
}
```

my contact converter:

```
    @FacesConverter(value = "contactConverter", forClass=Contact.class)
public class ContactConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private ContactDao contactDao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        return contactDao.getByContactName(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) { 
            return "";  
        } else { 
            return ((Contact) value).getLastName();
        }
    }
```

my client converter works.
my ContactDao:

```
public List<Contact> getByClient(Long idClient){
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE client_id = ?client_id");
    query.setParameter(PARAM_IDCLIENT, idClient);
    try{
        contacts = (List<Contact>) query.getResultList();
    }catch(NoResultException e){
        contacts.clear();
        Contact emptyList = new Contact();
        emptyList.setLastName("Aucune donnée");
        contacts.add(emptyList);
    }   
    return contacts;
}

public Contact getByContactName(String lastName){
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Contact e WHERE e.lastName = :lastName");
    query.setParameter(PARAM_LASTNAME, lastName);
    return (Contact) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

So, when I use the contactConverter, I have this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ac.imagine.beans.entities.Contact
at ac.imagine.beans.managed.ContactConverter.getAsString(ContactConverter.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getFormattedValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:521)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOption(MenuRenderer.java:534)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:794)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:847)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:297)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
```

When I don't use the contactconverter, my selectOneMenu displayed the ref of the Object, like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@20c5997e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem , 
I made createNativeQuery instead of createQuery, and he could not return an object Contact
the error was here :

```
public List<Contact> getByClient(Client client){
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Contact c WHERE c.client = :client_id");
    query.setParameter(PARAM_IDCLIENT, client);
    try{
        contacts = (List<Contact>) query.getResultList();
    }catch(NoResultException e){
        contacts = null;
        System.out.println("erruer lors de la recup des contacts");
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in getAsString method , so replace that :

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.equals("")) { 
        return "";  
    } else { 
        return ((Contact) value).getLastName();
    }
}
```

With that and look at the result :

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) {

        return ((Contact) value).getLastName();

}
```

Comment: I have try and I have the same message :

Comment: can you make sure that your importation for the converter class seems to be like those :
**import javax.faces.convert.Converter;**
**import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;**

Comment: yes it's : import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter; and import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

Comment: in the getAsString method cast the return result to String ( evenif the getLastName() return string ) , try **return String.valueOf(((Contact) value).getLastName())** ;

Comment: I had already tried that, for help : 2014-08-12T16:56:07.751+0200|Avertissement: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681)

Comment: look at this link it described the steps to create a custom converter  [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)